# Name of this Android UI element?

Tags: android, button

I have been looking for the name of that item but I don't know how to search correctly for its name. Can anyone tell me what the item is and some examples?

[image: Unknown item]

Comment: Its just a circular button with elevation. This elevation feature was introduced in lollipop that is in api level 21 and above you can give elevation to elements and also shadows. You can find more on android developer website and search there for material design.

Comment: Floating action button - http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button

Comment: here's a nice [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) to produce FABs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the component is `FloatingActionButton`. This concept was added in API 21 - Lollipop.

Here are some useful links about this element:

- [Floating action button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button) (explanation from google design)
- [Floating Action Buttons in Android Lollipop](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/floating-action-buttons-in-android-l/) (tutorial)
- [Floating Action Button – Part 1](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/floating-action-button-part-1/) (tutorial) *see also part 2 and 3*

Here are some libs:

- https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu
- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button
- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton
- https://github.com/shell-software/fab